# regex expression to allow only certain charaters Capital letters A-Z ' - and space

Tags: regex

I am new to regular expression. I have a requirement to validate a string in regular expression -

```
 Capital letters A-Z  '  - and space
```

I am new to this regex concepts -

```
and tried  [A-Z,',-]*    -> Any character in this class [A-Z,',/]. any number of repeatitions.
```

I tried to verify and i am not very confident because i havent specified that this regular expression can validate spaces even..
I appreciate if someone can give suggestion or provide little info if i am missing something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't separate chars with a comma in [], so you should use [A-Z' \-]*
You need to use \- because '-' has special meaning inside [].

Answer (score 2):

Commas are not needed inside character class. So following should work for you:

```
[A-Z' -]+
```

Which means:

```
A-Z      - Capital letters from A-Z (Range)
'        - Single Quote
" "      - Space (double quotes only to show you space)
-        - Hyphen (must appear as 1st or last in character class in order to avoid escaping
[A-Z' -]+ - Match 1 or more of the above allowed characters
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape special chars:' and -

`[A-Z\-\']*` should work.

Answer (score 0):

For Capital letters A-Z  '  - and space 
You could use `[A-Z\s\'\-]`
`\s` is for space, `\'` is for `'`, `\-` is for `-` , comma is not needed